# Wordpress - Redirect visitors from a specific country?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, countries

My client wants to redirect visitors from his country to a specific page and he doesn't want them to be able to see the site unless they enter the PIN on that specific page.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a geolocation fetch api something like, www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html‎

it will provide country name

then implement a switch case in your index page. , redirect page as per country.

[this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/geographical-redirect/) may help you.